# Styling SelectedRow in Rich:dataTable

Tags: javascript, css, richfaces

I have this `rich:dataTable`:

```
<rich:dataTable              
onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#B5CEFD'"
onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{org.richfaces.SKIN.tableBackgroundColor}'"     
onRowClick="this.style.backgroundColor='#b5F1F1'" 
rows="8" width="100%" id="tbl" value="#{..}" var="..">
//...
</rich:dataTable>
```

The `onRowClick` event works, but when I leave the row I lose that color after I click, because of the `onRowMouseOut` event, How to solve that and maintain the hovering effect?.
Do I need to add a CSS class?.
I am still having this problem, Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

CSS class is the way to go, instead of changing the background simply add/remove a class.

```
onrowclick="$(this).addClass('clicked')" 
onrowmousover="$(this).addClass('mouseover')"
```

That way you can define a different style for each situation:

```
.clicked { … }
.mouseover { … }
.clicked.mouseover { … }
```